# How to bind a property in itemtemplate to a proptery in itemsource?

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls, binding, observablecollection

Consider this container:

```
public class ItemInfo : DependencyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SomeDataItem> DataValues { get; set; }
    ...
    Dependency object registration and event handling
    ...
}

public class MyItemSource : ObservableCollection<ItemInfo>
{
   ...
}
```

Now, I wish to display this data in a listview where the control that displays the item is custom. For that, I'd set the MyItemSource to listview's ItemSource and define a ItemTemplate. However, it seems that I have no access to ItemInfo in the ItemTemplate. This is my XAML:

```
    <Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyStaticDataSource}" 
         Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:ItemInfoUserControl x:Name="itemInfoUserControl"
                Name = "{Binding Name}"       <--- this doesn't work
                Data = "{Binding DataValues}" <--- this doesn't work
                Width="300" Height="200"  
                Grid.Row="1">
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Instead of binding to ItemSource's ItemInfo, it binds to the ItemInfoUserControl properties, which is not what I wish it to do. Is there a way to bind properties in itemtemplate to a property in itemsource ? Or is there an alternative approach to what i'm ultimately trying to accomplish ?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it might be due to the fact that you're trying to set `x:Name` and `Name` at the same time. See my edit below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all you need to use proper [binding syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx#wpfdatabinding_pt1_updated_topic2):

```
Name = "{Binding Name}"
```

and

```
Data = "{Binding DataValues}"
```

Instead of just "`Name = "Binding Name"`" and "`Data = "Binding DataValues"`". Note the addition of "`{`" and "`}`" around your binding expression.
This might be enough to solve your problem, as long as `Name` and `DataValues` are `DependencyProperties` in `ItemInfoUserControl`. If not, you'll need to implement them as `DependencyProperties` in order to be able to bind to them in XAML. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx) for a good MSDN article on defining custom dependency properties.

---

**Edit:** Also, just noticed -- you're setting both `x:Name` and `Name`. From [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290.aspx) on MSDN:

> If Name is available as a property on the class, Name and x:Name can be used interchangeably as attributes, but a parse exception will result if both are specified on the same element. If the XAML is markup compiled, the exception will occur on the markup compile, otherwise it occurs on load.

Remove `x:Name="itemInfoUserControl"` and see if that helps.

Comment: Um, sorry, I was in a hurry. Actually the binding syntax was a typo when posting this here and I do have dependencyproperties defined.

Comment: `Name={Binding Path=Name}` and `Name={Binding Name}` are equivalent. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189022(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Noup, removing "x:Name" doesn't help. I tried doing something like this also: 

{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=Name}

But that also doesn't work..

Comment: Hmm. Maybe try changing the name of your DependencyProperty in ItemInfoUserControl from "Name" to "ControlName"? Perhaps there's some sort of collision since Name is already defined...

Comment: Do you have it working ? Can you provide a working example so that I could diff it ?

Comment: I don't have it working, sorry. How are you defining `MyStaticDataSource`?

Comment: <l:MyItemSource  x:Key="MyStaticDataSource"/> 
But that shouldn't be it as in the output window the error message is: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'GraphName' property not found on 'object' ''Graph' (Name='graph')'. BindingExpression:Path=ItemName; DataItem='Graph' (Name='graph'); target element is 'GraphTicker' (Name='parent'); target property is 'Name' (type 'String')